# How to run groovy script using crontab?

Tags: cron, cron-task

I've tried to run a groovy script, using crontab:

`16 21    * * *   root   groovy /home/vasily/test.groovy`

But I have an error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: groovy: not found
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a bash script, something like this

```
#!/bin/sh

JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_12

GROOVY_HOME=/home/jboss/groovy-1.7.5

export JAVA_HOME

export GROOVY_HOME

PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$GROOVY_HOME/bin:

export PATH

cd /home/jboss/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/flt/conf/scripts

(Assuming that Groovy script located at /home/jboss/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/flt/conf/scripts)

groovy -classpath /home/jboss/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/flt/conf/scripts /home/jboss/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/flt/conf/scripts/test.groovy
```

and within the crontab you can call your bash script

Comment: /home/vasily/run.sh: 9: /home/vasily/run.sh: groovy: not found